# Error ibtoold[1345:11688] DEBUG: Added to environment: (Error running xamarin forms in IOS)

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run `Xamarin Forms` application. The `Android` version works fine both in mobile and emulator. However, the `IOS` platform doesn't work and throws an error while debugging. I have configured host and guest machine through `Oracle VM VirtualBox`. The VirtualBox contains `MacOS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A471t)` with `XCode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)` and the host is a `Windows 10  Pro` running `Visual Studio 2019`. The error is somehow not descriptive and googling doesn't help.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     2020-01-18 06:27:29.051 ibtoold[1345:11688] DEBUG: Added to
>   environment: {
>       TMPDIR = "/var/folders/wc/xhn6f1ss4tzc9mjf2qmjkdhc0000gn/T/25F2BE0D-5707-44D6-84E0-787D8E0AB37D";
>   } 2020-01-18 06:27:30.617 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.629 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.630 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.630 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon152.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.631 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon167.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.631 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon180.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.632 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon180.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.633 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon20.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.633 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon29.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.634 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.635 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.636 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.637 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon58.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.637 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon58.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.638 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon60.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.638 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon76.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.639 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon80.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.639 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon80.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.640 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   Unable to get image dimensions for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon87.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.651 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon180.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.651 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.652 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon20.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.652 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.652 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.653 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon80.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.653 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon167.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.653 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon76.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.653 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon152.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.653 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.654 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon58.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.654 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon87.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.654 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon58.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.654 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon29.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.655 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon180.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.655 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.655 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.655 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon80.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.656 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12623]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon60.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.750 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12790]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon80.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.755 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12790]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.758 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12816]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.758 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12814]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon80.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.759 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12815]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon58.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.761 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12816]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon167.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.762 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12814]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon58.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.763 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12790]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon152.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.766 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12790]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon120.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.767 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12814]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon60.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.768 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12815]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon20.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.770 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12790]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.771 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12814]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon1024.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.772 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12815]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon29.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.775 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12815]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon40.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.776 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12814]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon87.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.778 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12816]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon76.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.778 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12813]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon180.png
>   2020-01-18 06:27:30.779 IBCocoaTouchImageCatalogTool[1349:12813]
>   CoreThemeDefinition: Unable to create image for
>   file:///Users/dev/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/Dest2.iOS/99911007fc8315ab04a9f6c03da0738d/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/cloned-assets/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon180.png Dest2.iOS

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not legal to run macOS on Oracle VM.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error while running on a real macbook air, from a windows 10 machine using Visual Studio 2019:

> error : 2020-10-25 21:56:18.764 ibtoold[2996:61157] DEBUG: Added to environment: {

Looks like the error message is cut at the end, but I don't have more in the build log.
This happened after I edited the info.plist file and defined there a wrong path to the xcasset:

> <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
> <string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcons1.appiconset</string>